# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.MSmerge_contents' with unique index

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, replication, merge-replication

We have Merge replication configured between 1 publisher and 12 subscribers all having SQL server 2008 R2

On one of the subscription I am getting below error

```
Error messages:
The merge process could not replicate one or more UPDATE statements to the 'Subscriber' because a stored procedure failed to execute. Troubleshoot by using SQL Profiler. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147200989)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL-2147200989
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.MSmerge_contents' with unique index 'nc2MSmerge_contents'. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 2601)
Get help: http://help/2601
```

In the error its mentioned that " `Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.MSmerge_contents' with unique index 'nc2MSmerge_contents'`" I checked `nc2MSmerge_contents` index script but there is no unique constraint specified for the index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nc2MSmerge_contents] ON [dbo].[MSmerge_contents] 
(
    [generation] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Below is the table structure

[image]

I need to fix this without dropping/recreating the subscription. Can anyone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was that database and indexes were corrupted. fixed after following below link

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16113/unique-index-corrupted-sql-select-query-returns-single-row-but-create-unique-in